# Photoshop script for resizing (output=png, nearest neighbor compatibility)?

Tags: photoshop, image-resizing

So I'm resizing about 1000 pixel art images, and I'm looking for a way to batch render them, but I need to preserve the transparency of the background, and I need to keep the pixels intact. I am doubling the images in size, saving the output as a PNG file to preserve transparency, and I have to make sure the interpolation method is Nearest Neighbor. Bicubic, or whatever the default is, gives me blurry output.

The default image processor script has no option for PNG output, and even when I change the default Image Interpolation in Preferences to Nearest Neighbor, this script still does bicubic. I'm not sure if there's actually any way to do this or not, but it would save me a ton of time if I could find a way to do this. I tried using InfranView to batch resize, but the images came out blurry there too.

Comment: Sounds like an obvious job for **ImageMagick** which can do them all in parallel. Please show sample input and output images and what processing you are doing.

Comment: I don't think I can post images directly on Stack Overflow, so here is an imgur link with the start and end product. https://imgur.com/a/JVeAepK

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Are all images the same size (initially)? If yes, you can record an action and batch process it.

Comment: The images you link to are not PNGs with transparency, they are picture of PNGs overlaid on a chessboard background!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

The basic command in Terminal (or Command Prompt in Windows) is:

```
magick input.png -scale 200% result.png
```

That will turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

If that looks good to you, you can scale all the PNG files in your current directory and save the up-scaled images into a new directory called BIG like this:

```
mkdir BIG
magick mogrify -path BIG -scale 200% *.png
```

As always, I would suggest you make a backup first. If you are on a decent OS, i.e. macOS or Linux, you can get the, all done even faster in parallel if the above is too slow - just ask. If you want to resize to a different size, just ask. If you are on macOS, install **ImageMagick** with **homebrew**, i.e. `brew install imagemagick`.